# Can "(T)here you are!" be used as exclamation to a discovery?

Tags: idioms, inversion

I have often heard and always thought that people exclaim "(T)here you are!" when they, for example, found someone they've been looking for. So much so that I was pretty surprised to learn that that phrase is used for handing someone something. However, there is no definition for an exclamation to a discovery, and I have always used "Here you go" when giving someone something.

Thus, can "(T)here you are!" be used to mean the first definition?

Comment: I think this idiomatic usage of exclamatory *There you are!* is more common in BrE than AmE - and I'm pretty sure many Americans find the near-equivalent BrE *There you go!* rather "peculiar". The actual *meaning* is similar to the French ***Voila**!* (something has been found, or some problem has been solved / explained; the words aren't to be interpreted *literally*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, not true. If you are looking for someone in AmE, you might very well say: There you are or Here you are. to mean: You are at this place. But it also is  the performative statement for handing something to someone. It is also used to say: So there! I was right. I should probably put in a formal answer.

Comment: Those are both "literal" usages. I remember the American "New York cop on horseback" TV series (McCloud, I think), who more than once expressed befuddlement over the BrE form ***There you go**!* used in the same figurative sense as ***Voila**!* (which itself is often used by Anglophones with that sense). Sometimes equivalent to ***Hey presto**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The expression is exactly the same in AmE English for things or as performatives. Same as Voilà. For: Here it is, There is it. Sometimes: There you go.

Comment: I'd have thought *most* instances of the exact text "There you go" would be literal usages on both sides of the pond, but according to NGrams "prevalence" values for the AmE and BrE corpuses, the latter is about 50% higher than the former. I can't think why that would be, unless some significant fraction of Americans *don't* use the ***go*** version so figuratively. I guess it's possible McCloud (who was a bit "rustic", obviously) was perfectly familiar with the usage, but simply found it "peculiar" when interpreted literally.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ngrams does not know how people **speak**. Writing is not proof of speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you are!

**FINDING THINGS**

- Two people are driving along a country road trying to find an driveway entrance partially hidden by bushes. One person says "I drove around for 20 minutes and could not find it". They continue down the road, and suddenly see the entrance and the second person says: "There you are. It really is here".
- Two people are looking for a small stone statue in the remains of a fire in a building. One person finds it, *holds it up* and says to the other: "There you are! You see? It really was hidden under the ashes".

**HANDING THINGS OVER** [Usually, used with here, not there.]

- Here you are! [A man hands files another man needs to him in an office.
- Here you are! [One person hands a coffee they just bought at a counter to another person.

Both of those can be expressed as *Here you go!* also, in AmE.

[This is a performative statement where the words carry out the action, so to speak.]

**ARGUMENTATION**

- Two people are arguing. A third person says something that resolves the issue. The first person then says to the second person: **There you go!** Or: **There you are!** You see, I was right.

There you go. in that sense is the same thing as: There it is. where it refers to the subject at hand.

Please note: All the above could be Voilà as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was greatly dumbfounded when I heard people say "(T)here you are" because I had used "go" instead my whole life.